# Solutions to ODE: $y'=y^{1/3}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to find all tuples $(a,b,x_0,y_0)\in\mathbb{R}^4$ such that $a<x_0<b$ and there is a solution for the differential equation $y'=y^{1/3}$ on $(a,b)$ satisfying $f(x_0)=y_0$, and all solutions for each such tuple.

Take such a tuple $(a,b,x_0,y_0)$. If I assume that $y(x)\neq0$ for every $x\in(a,b)$, then I get $y(x)=\pm(\frac{2}{3}x+(y_0^{2/3}-\frac{2}{3}x_0))^{3/2}$ and $x_0-\frac{3}{2}y_0^{2/3}\notin(a,b)$. This describes all solution which don't vanish in the open interval in which they're defined.

What about the solutions that do vanish somewhere? Obviously, for every tuple $(a,b,x_0,0)$, I have the solution $y(x)=0$. Are there others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm interpreting $y^{1/3}$ as $y^{1/3}:={\rm sgn}\, y\>|y|^{1/3}$.

The given ODE 
$$y'=f(x,y):=y^{1/3}\tag{1}$$ defines a slope-field in all of ${\mathbb R}^2$. This field is invariant under horizontal translation, which implies that the field of solution curves has the same translational symmetry. The function $f$ is continuous throughout and satisfies the assumptions of the existence and uniqueness theorem at all points $(x_0,y_0)$ with $y_0\ne0$. It follows that there is exactly one local solution through all  points $(x_0,y_0)$ with $y_0\ne0$ and at least one solution through the points $(x_0,0)$.
It is easy to check that the curves (Neil parabolas)
$$y(x)=\pm\left({2x\over3}\right)^{3/2}\qquad(x\geq0)\tag{2}$$
solve $(1)$, and so does the curve $y(x)\equiv0$. Since the translational copies of the curves $(2)$ already cover all of ${\mathbb R}^2\setminus\{\hbox{$x$-axis}\}$ we don't have to look further.

But the initial points $(x_0,0)$ are special. Through these points not only passes the special solution $y(x)\equiv0$. In each of them also begin two halves of a Neil parabola. It follows that the initial value problem at $(x_0,0)$ has three solution germs, namely the function $y(x)\equiv0$ and the two functions
$$y(x):=\cases{\pm \left({2(x-x_0)\over3}\right)^{3/2}\qquad&$(x\geq x_0)$ \cr
0&$(x<x_0)$\cr}\ .$$
(Here two solutions are considered the same, if they coincide in a neighborhood of $x_0$. That's meant by the word "germ".)

When we now look at the full solution portrait we can see that for all initial points $(x_0,y_0)$ with $y_0\ne0$ there is exactly one global solution, which is defined for $-\infty<x<\infty$, and is $\equiv0$ for all "large negative" $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for instance, for any $\delta>0$
$$
y(x)=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if }x\le x_0+\delta,\\
\Bigl(\dfrac23(x-x_0-\delta)\Bigr)^{3/2} & \text{if }x>x_0+\delta,
\end{cases}
$$
is a solution defined on $(-\infty,\infty)$.